# Attached database file and "The login failed" error

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I implement a windows application and a windows service with an attached database file for both of them with this connection string:

```
Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=d:\Resources\SamaDB.mdf;Database=SamaDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=True
```

It seems that every things are ok. The windows application runs well when the windows service is stopped, But when the windows service application starts, The windows application raised the bellow error :

```
"Cannot open database 'SamaDB' requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user '026-36661762\PouyanComputer'".
```

Answer (score 0):

try Integrated Security=true (instead: SSPI)

Answer (score 0):

Change the service login using **026-36661762\PouyanComputer** account. Like below:

[image]

Comment: thanks.it seems, the problem solved. but database operations is slow on both side(win app & win service app). what will it be if the user change his password?

Comment: The service will be stopped, I guess. You need to retype the new password and start the service again.

Comment: However, if this solves your problem please accept the answer. Follow the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers